# How to pass paramters in IN Clause and one more paramter in jdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a query which accepts one IN clause parameter and one simple where clause parameter like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE empId in (?) and empName = ?
```

I was trying to use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` but it accepts only IN clause parameters in `MapSqlParameterSource`.

```
List<String> empList = namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, parameters,String.class);
```

Below is my code snippet.

```
String query="Select count(*) from employee where empId in (?) and empName =?";
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(appType.split(" , ")));

   MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
   parameters.addValue("listOfId", list);

   List<String> empList = 
      namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, parameters,String.class);
```

How to pass another parameter i.e `empName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your parameters:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE empId in (:listOfId) and empName = :empName
```

And then add it to `parameters`

```
parameters.addValue("listOfId", list);
parameters.addValue("empName", empName);
```